# JQuery that works in a JSfiddle not working on a WordPress site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have some code that works just fine in a fiddle, but not in wordpress. Essentially, I want the div 'loading' to be hidden by default, but show for 3 seconds and then ease out on a button click.

My JS is loaded in the footer, and the 'loading' div, as well as the trigger are within a page. I have tried moving the JQuery into the header to see if that would help, but so far, no. I am sure the javascript file is being loaded. Can anyone help with what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code. Thank you very much.

```
<div id ="loading">
next page is loading
</div>

<span id="button">Button</span>
```

```
jQuery( function( $ ){

  $("#bottom").on("click", function() {
    $("#loading").show(0, function() {
      $("#loading").fadeOut (3000);
    });
  });
  $("#loading").hide();
  
  });
```

```
#loading{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  }
```

Comment: did you include the jquery library in your files?

Comment: I did, yes. Other JQuery is working, just not this instance.

Comment: Did you add jquery as a dependency when enqueuing your javascript file? This can help sometimes. Please edit your answer to include the important lines from your functions.php file. Additionally, check the console for errors and post here if need assistance with those.

Comment: I did, yes. Here is the code from my functions file:
`function myprefix_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 
      'custom-script',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', 
      array('jquery'),
      '1.0.0',
      true );
  }`

Comment: And when you say that you are sure the file is being loaded, it's been tested with an alert or checking the network tab in dev tools? Any console errors too?

Comment: Yeah, I tested by logging a message to the console. No errors.

Answer (score 0):

You had spelled `button` wrong, so I am surprised it worked on JSfiddle.

```
$("#bottom").on(...
```

instead of:

```
$("#button").on(...
```

Full Code:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#button").on("click", function() {
    $("#loading").show(0, function() {
      $("#loading").fadeOut(3000);
    });
  });
  $("#loading").hide();
});
```

```css
#loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading" style="display: none !important;">
  next page is loading
</div>

<span id="button">Button</span>
```

Comment: Good catch, thank you for pointing out the typo, but it still doesn't work. When I load the page with the #loading element, it is visible before clicking, where it should only display when clicking the trigger element. I tried changing the initial visibility, but that still doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Could you please provided the rest of your code, because some other element may be affecting it. Also try adding inline CSS, using `!important` to the `#loading` element by adding: `style="display: none !important;"`.

Comment: I added the inline CSS to the `#loading` element. Try it now!

Comment: Thanks, that works great in the fiddle, but still a no go in wordpress. I think you're right about some kind of conflict.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's just a simple typo.
in the HTML the ID is `button`

```
<span id="button">Button</span>
```

and in JS you refer to `bottom`

```
 $("#bottom").on("click", function() {
```